# Azure Function AppInsights spamming logging

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to disable logging in a deployed Azure Function on the Microsoft Azure platform.

Locally only my custom Information logs appear. On Azure App Insights log stream however, a great number more appear: So many that the console is flooded in seconds. There are logs for Requests, Responses, DbCommands etc. There is even logging that says "Executing function (Reason=)". Again, locally these logs are disabled through `host.json` but on Azure they show up regardless.

What I've tried:

- Setting log levels in `host.json` to `"default" : "Warning"` and `"Function": "Warning"`
- Setting `maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond` to `0` in `applicationInsights.samplingSettings`
- Setting `excludedTypes` in `applicationInsights.samplingSettings`
- Disabling Telemetry logging through `Startup.cs`

Nothing worked. The logs still appear in droves.
[image]

Does anyone know how to get rid of them? I want to see only **my own** Information logs. The rest of the log levels should be Warning at minimum or not be shown.

Thanks!

`host.json` file looks like this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "RestApiFunctions.Functions": "Information",
      "RestApiFunctions.SignalR": "Information",
      "DataLayer": "Information",
      "ServiceLayer": "Information",
      "Function": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Trace;Request"
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "openApi": {
    "info": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "title": "INEX Cloud REST API"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "customHeaders": {
        "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-Total-Count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your full host.json file

Comment: @PeterBons added to the original post

Answer (score 1):

When application insights is configured for Azure Function it has its severity level set to "Information" (instead of "Warning" in case of any other (web) app).

To change the log level for application insights you need to change it at a different place in the host.config file, like this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "RestApiFunctions.Functions": "Information",
      "RestApiFunctions.SignalR": "Information",
      "DataLayer": "Information",
      "ServiceLayer": "Information",
      "Function": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Trace;Request"
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "openApi": {
    "info": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "title": "INEX Cloud REST API"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "customHeaders": {
        "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-Total-Count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, do mind the following:

> **Caution**
>
> Azure Functions integrates with Application Insights by storing telemetry events in Application Insights tables. Setting a category log level to any value different from Information will prevent the telemetry to flow to those tables. As outcome, you won't be able to see the related data in Application Insights or Function Monitor tab.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels))

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The same logs still flood the AppInsights console.